# Proper way to store api config in vue js client

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js SPA which communicates with an api. This api has an endpoint to get general settings about it. I need these in my SPA, but don't want to make a request every time I need them.

These are somewhat fixed, but can change - I don't know them when I build the application so I can't just statically compile them in my SPA.

1. I've tried creating a simple module like this one:

```
import {HTTP} from './http-common'

export default {
    config: null,

    getConfig() {
        return this.config
    },

    initConfig() {
        return HTTP.get('info')
            .then(r => {
                this.config = r.data
            })
    }
}
```

I then did this in my `main.js` file, before creating the vue instance:

```
import config from './config'
config.initConfig()
    .then(() => {
        Vue.prototype.$config = config.getConfig()
    })
```

The problem with this is I don't have a good method of knowing in my components if the config has been initialized or if the request is still pending or has been successfully loaded. I could check if `this.$config === null` but then, if it is I'd need to put the whole thing in a `setTimeout` or so which feels a bit hacky.

2. I also thought of just including my config module from above anywhere I need it and calling `config.getConfig()` everytime I need the value.
3. Vuex may also be a solution, but my SPA is quite simple (at least for now) and I would rather avoid the additional complexity of Vuex when I don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that instead of doing that in your main.js file directly you do it in your root component. For arguments sake we will call it App.vue

```
<template>
  <div
    v-if="appReady"
    id="app"
  >
    // Other template stuff here
  </div>
<script>
import {HTTP} from './http-common'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      config: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    appReady () {
      return !!this.config
    }
  },
  beforeCreate () {
    HTTP.get('info')
      .then(r => {
        this.config = r.data
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

Then simply access config in other components by calling `this.$root.config` when using JS or in the template by calling `$root.config`

Comment: Further consideration you could add a data key of config and then reference it from anywhere in your application like `this.$root.config`

Comment: It seems like accessing `this.$root.config` from a child component does not work.

Edit: I did something like this:
```
  beforeCreate() {
   config.initConfig()
     .then(() => {
      this.config = config.getConfig()
      this.appReady = true
     })
  },
```

Comment: did you add config to your data object of the root componenet?

Comment: data () {
    return {
      appReady: false,
      config: null
    }
  },

Comment: Yes, I added it to the data object.

Comment: There must be another problem. See simplified example https://jsfiddle.net/2mw9a8xc/

Comment: Hmmmm... I guess it makes a difference if my child component is a "real" vue component (like in your example) or loaded via a route? (using the vue js router)

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you put together a simple example so I can help you debug? Also did you implement the v-if since you need to wait for the promise to be satisfied?

Comment: Actually looking at your code this wont work, config is null

Comment: See updated example. Before the promise wasn't satisfied when you were using the getConfig method.

Comment: I updated following your example, but it still did not work. The exact error I get is `TypeError: "this.$root.config is undefined"`, so I guess the child component just does not have access to the root component at all.

Comment: @kolaente if you would like to post your code I am sure we can help you are clearly having issues elsewhere in your code. Child components absolutely have access to $root if they are wired up correctly, even through the router. Here is a simple example https://jsfiddle.net/7bm5jew9/